# How to have daily error and access logs on Apache (for Windows)?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, logging

We're running Apache 2.2.9 (Win32) with a few virtual hosts configured on the one server. Each has it's own ErrorLog and CustomLog settings which are in the format of "logs/[domain name]-error.log" and "logs/[domain name]-access.log". Unfortunately these are now creating quite large files.

On IIS you can specify the log schedule, which can put them in a daily format of "yymmdd.log". Is there something similar I can do here?

It doesn't have to be daily either, weekly or monthly will do. I'd just like to break them up so that we can keep X amount instead of everything it's ever logged. A quick Google seems to bring up lots of Linux orientated answers involving log splitters, scripts and cron jobs which isn't too helpful for a Windows installation.

**Update**

Thanks to radius, I tweaked my **httpd-vhosts.conf** to use Apache's built in **rotatelogs** command, in the following format:

`ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/[domain name]-error.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 5M"
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs logs/[domain name]-access.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S.log 5M" common`

They'll create a new log file when the current one reaches 5MB. I know that's not daily as asked for, but that keeps them at a manageable size which will do. I did try the rotate after so many seconds but it didn't seem to be putting the time stamp in the file name correctly (specifically hours, minutes and seconds).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is the rotatelogs program that comes with apache
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

For instance, to rotate your logs daily at midnight:

```
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs -f /var/log/apache2/logfile.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400" common
```

Comment: +1, didn't know Apache had a solution of it's own.

Comment: For anyone using Ubuntu you might need to change the path to `/usr/bin/rotatelogs`, as that is where `rotatelogs` is found. Otherwise Apache will fail to restart due to an error.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called log rotation.

Google seems to list some revelant links about log rotation tools for windows.

This seems like an Apache specific solution, maybe it'll help you:

http://www.sprint.net.au/~terbut/usefulbox/apachelogrot.htm

Answer (score 0):

Docs here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Try direct with

```
CustomLog "|C:/<chemin vers apache>/bin/rotatelogs.exe E:/<chemin vers les logs>/<monsite>/access-%Y_%m_%d.log 86400 60" combined
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of what this does.